# Non so che significa questo 'cadere come un peso *** '

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Che significa 'cadere come un peso *** '?

Se si può spiegare anche in inglese, mi sarebbe veramente utile.
Però in italiano va anche bene.

Comment: could you please explain what do you mean with '***'? The phrase "cadere come un peso" can be translated litterally as "fall like a weight", but it has no particular meaning out of the context in which it is used.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are referring to the expression "*cadere come un peso morto*" which corresponds to the English expression "*fall/drop/sink  [like a stone](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/drop-fall-sink-like-a-stone)*". (Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

La risposta di Josh61 è perfetta, la mia è solo una considerazione sull'uso dell'espressione:

In italiano si dice (almeno dalle mie parti) "cadere *a* peso morto". Se si vuole usare "*come un"* è forse meglio dire "cadere come una pera cotta" che siginifica "cedimento improvviso e vistoso (dovuto per esempio alla fatica)" oppure usare "cadere come un *corpo* morto" (Dante scriveva "E caddi come corpo morto cade" nell'Inferno).

Comment: Translation: josh61's answer is perfect, but I want to add just a thing: in Italian is (where I live) "cadere a peso morto". If you want to use "come un" it's better " cadere come una pera cotta" that means " unexpected and flashy yielding (for the fatigue, for example)" or "cadere come un corpo morto" (Dante wrote in his Inferno "E caddi come un corpo morto cade").